# Let p(n) be the probability that exactly n tosses of a fair coin are needed before two consecutive heads; q(n) be the sum of p(k)

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Let p(n) be the probability that exactly n tosses of a fair coin are needed before heads is seen twice
in a row.
Let q(n) = $\sum_{k≥n} p(k)$.

Find closed-form expressions for q(n)

I have only reached so far: since finding this probability equals finding（n-3) tosses without two consecutive heads out of $2^n$ toss, (since for above tosses we can add it with THH to construct two heads at the end) . It equals $$\frac{F_{n-1}}{2^n}$$where F denote the Fibonacci number.

Now my questions is :
what does q(n) mean? How to find an expression for it?

Can I directly say: it is (1- $\sum_{k =1,2,...n-1} p(k)$ ) ?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Are you familiar with Binet's formula? If yes, then you can convert $q(n)$ into the sum of 2 geometric progressions.

Comment: $q(n)$ is the probability that it will take **at least** $n$ tosses.